# How do you create multiple sprite objects moving sideways using pygame(like T-rex game)

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite

I have tried searching for many solutions to do this but I cant seem to understand how to spawn the enemy block multiple times. In my program , the enemy block will only appear once. The game is incomplete, so please ignore empty functions.

I have created the enemy object using sprites. I want to create the program in such a way that , once the enemy object leaves the screen , another object(same size and colour) will appear.

```
import pygame as pg

from settings import *
from sprites import *
from os import path


class Game(object):
    """docstring for Game"""
    def __init__(self):
        # initialise game
        global points , game_speed
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((s_HEIGHT , s_WIDTH))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.icon = pg.image.load("C:/Users/DELL/Documents/Jump Cube/Img/cube.png")
        pg.display.set_icon(self.icon)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.running = True
        self.game_speed = 14
        points = 0
        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)

        self.load_data()



    def load_data(self):
        self.dir = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_dir = path.join(self.dir, "Img")
        #load spritesheet image
        self.spritesheet = Spritesheet(path.join(img_dir, SPRITESHEET))


    def new(self):
        # Stars a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.ene = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        pl = Platform(0, s_HEIGHT - 230, 800, 40)
        en = enemies(50, 50)
        self.all_sprites.add(pl)
        self.platforms.add(pl)
        self.all_sprites.add(en)
        self.ene.add(en)
        self.Run()

    def Run(self):
        # Game Loop
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.Events()
            self.Update()
            self.Draw()
            self.score()

    def Update(self):
        # Game Loop - Update
        self.all_sprites.update()
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)
        if hits:
            self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
            self.player.vel.y = 0
        pass

    def score(self):
        global points , game_speed
        points += 1
        if points % 100 == 0:
            game_speed += 1

        text = font.render("Points : " + str(points), True, WHITE)
        textrec = text.get_rect()
        textrec.center = (700, 50)
        self.screen.blit(text, textrec)

    def Events(self):
        # Game Loop - Events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.player.jump()

    def Draw(self):
        # Game Loop - Draw
        self.screen.fill(BLACK)
        self.score()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.update()
        pass

    def start_screen(self):
        # shows the start screen
        pass

    def end_screen(self):
        # shows the end screen
        pass

g = Game()
g.start_screen()

while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.end_screen()

pg.quit()
```

sprites.py

```
import pygame as pg
from settings import *
vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Spritesheet():
    # utility class for laoding and parsing spritesheets
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pg.image.load(filename).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        # grabs images from large spritesheets
        image = pg.Surface((width, height))
        image.blit(self.spritesheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        image = pg.transform.scale(image , (50, 85))
        return image

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = self.game.spritesheet.get_image(614, 1063, 120, 191)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (s_WIDTH / 2, s_HEIGHT / 2)
        self.pos = vec(100, 600)
        self.vel = (0, 0)
        self.acc = (0, 0)

    def jump(self):
        #jump only if standing on plat
        self.rect.y += 1
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.platforms, False)
        self.rect.y -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = -8

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, PLAYER_GRAV)
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

class Platform(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class enemies(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, w1, h1):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w1, h1))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 700
        self.rect.y = 517

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= game_speed
```

settings.py

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#game options
TITLE = "Ninja Jump"
s_WIDTH = 600
s_HEIGHT = 800
FPS = 60
game_speed = 14
points = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)

SPRITESHEET = "spritesheet_jumper.png"

#player properties
PLAYER_ACC = 0.5
PLAYER_GRAV = 0.3

#colors
WHITE = (199, 198, 196)
BLACK = (23, 23, 23)
GRAY = (121, 121, 120)
GREEN = (72, 161, 77)
BLACK1 = (0,0,0)
GRAY1 = (162, 162, 162)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of `enemies` should be name `Enemy`. The class represents 1 single enemy. The coordinates of the enemy are arguments of the constructor. The `en`  [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) object is used to manage multiple enemies:

```py
class Enemies(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w1, h1):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((w1, h1))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= game_speed
```

```py
class Game(object):
    # [...]

    self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.ene = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        pl = Platform(0, s_HEIGHT - 230, 800, 40)
      
        en1 = Enemy(700, 517, 50, 50)
        en2 = Enemy(600, 517, 50, 50)
        en3 = Enemy(500, 517, 50, 50)

        self.all_sprites.add(pl)
        self.platforms.add(pl)
        self.all_sprites.add([en1, en2, en3])
        self.ene.add([en1, en2, en3])
        self.Run()
```